# Evaluate sum similar to the binomial theorem modulo 5

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}2^{3k}\bmod 5$$

I tried changing $2^{3k}$ into $\sqrt{2^3}^{2k+1}$, then substituting $j=\frac k 2 - 1$ and using the binomial theorem, resulting in $\frac 1 {\sqrt{2^3}}(1+\sqrt{2^3})^{2n+1}-2n+1 \bmod 5$, but this doesn't seem to be right, and I don't know what to do with the $\bmod 5$.

Comment: $$
\sum_{i\text{ odd }}\binom{k}{i}x^i=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i}\binom{k}{i}x^i-\sum_{i}\binom{k}{i}(-x)^i\right)=\frac{(1+x)^k-(1-x)^k}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [an alternative to using the field $\Bbb{F}_{25}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/913356/11619) I proffer the following.

Let's denote your sum by $S_n$.
We have the identity (also pointed out by Paolo Leonetti)
$$
f(x,k):=\sum_{2\nmid i,0<i\le k}\binom k i x^i=\frac{(1+x)^k-(1-x)^k}2.
$$
This implies that
$$
S_n=f(\sqrt8,2n+1)=\frac{(1+\sqrt8)^{2n+1}-(1-\sqrt8)^{2n+1}}2.
$$
The polynomial
$$
p(T)=(T-(1+\sqrt8)^2)(T-(1-\sqrt8)^2)=T^2-18T+49
$$
has $(1\pm\sqrt8)^2$ as its zeros. By a standard result on linear recurrences this implies that the sequence $(S_n)$ follow the recurrence relation
$$
S_{n+2}-18S_{n+1}+49S_n=0
$$
for all integers $n\ge0$.

Turning this into a modulo five relation gives
$$
S_{n+2}\equiv 3S_{n+1}+S_n\pmod5.
$$
As $S_0=1$ and $S_1=11$ from this it follows that the remainders modulo five follow the pattern
$$
(1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2,
  3,\ldots)
$$
that clearly repeats with a period twelve. Periodicity can be proven by induction using the recurrence relation, or by rewriting the recurrence using a matrix.

Many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Where did the polynomial come from? What is the significance of it?

Comment: @Joald It may be easier to work it out backwards. The recurrence relation $S_{n+2}-18S_{n+1}+49S_n=0$ comes with the characteristic equation with roots $r_{1,2}=(1\pm\sqrt8)^2$. The roots are distinct so all the solutions are of the form $S_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$ with some constants $A,B$. The formula shows that your sequence has this form. Therefore it satisfies the recurrence relation. In other words, a piece of reverse engineering. The treatment in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ goes the other way.

Comment: I like this solution, but let's be honest: the one you were referring to gives more insight. In the notation you chose, there, $1+\alpha$ is a generator of the field (and, btw, $1-\alpha=(1+\alpha)^5)$, so $(1+\alpha)^{24}=1$. Now we have an exponent $2n+1$ (step $2$), so it's clear the period has to be $12$. And it's also clear we can't expect some closed formula in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for your feedback. I see it more or less the same way. I couldn't really close this as a duplicate (for many reasons), so I had to come up with an alternative way of doing it, and actually produce the sequence. I quite agree that this way leaves the origin of the period length in the dark. We can, of course jot down the matrix in $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_5)$ that gives the evolution from $(S_n,S_{n+1})$ to $(S_{n+1},S_{n+2})$, and check that it is of order twelve. Still, that is somehow unsatisfactory.